# Sightly component ignores my clientLib (doesn't include links to css)

Tags: aem, sightly, client-library

I use example from : [blogs.adobe.com](https://blogs.adobe.com/experiencedelivers/experience-management/htl-clientlibs/)
but my output html file doesn't include links to my css files.

boilerplateSightlyPage.html:

```
<html>
<sly data-sly-include="head.html" data-sly-unwrap />
<sly data-sly-include="/libs/wcm/core/components/init/init.jsp" data-sly-unwrap />
<body>
    <div data-sly-test="${wcmmode.edit}"> 
        <!--/* Show only in edit (author) mode */-->
        <h1>Simple Page Component Using Sightly</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="flex-row"> 
        <div class="col-half">First column</div>
        <div class="col-half">Second column</div> 
    </div>

<div data-sly-resource="${@path='par',resourceType='wcm/foundation/components/parsys'}"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

head.html:

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv=”content-type” content=”text/html; charset=UTF-8” />
<sly data-sly-use.clientlib="/libs/granite/sightly/templates/clientlib.html"
    data-sly-call="${clientlib.css @ categories='alexpi, flex'}"/>

<title>${currentPage.title}</title>
</head>
```

clientLib :
/etc/designs/alexpi-training/clientLib 
properties: 
jcr:primaryType (Name)cq:ClientLibraryFolder 
categories (String[]) alexpi, flex

css.txt:

```
#base=css
flex.css
first.css
```

CSS files location: 
/etc/designs/alexpi-training/clientLib/css/first.css 
/etc/designs/alexpi-training/clientLib/css/flex.css

I see 'head.html' was included:

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="”content-type”" content="”text/html;" charset="UTF-8”">
<title>AP empty sightly page with clienlib</title>

<link rel="stylesheet"href="/libs/cq/gui/components/authoring/clientlibs/page.css" type="text/css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/libs/granite/author/deviceemulator/clientlibs.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/libs/cq/gui/components/authoring/clientlibs/page.js"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: I think your problem may be connected with multiple categories. Maybe there is some whitespace character in your clientlib defintion for example before ` flex`. To check that try to remove one of categories and then just include one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to pass an array via an `option` you need to use `${myVar @ optName=[myVar, 'string']}` syntax, [read here](https://github.com/Adobe-Marketing-Cloud/htl-spec/blob/master/SPECIFICATION.md#116-options)

in your head.html:

```
<sly data-sly-use.clientlib="/libs/granite/sightly/templates/clientlib.html"
    data-sly-call="${clientlib.css @ categories=['alexpi', 'flex']}"/>
```

note: **`categories=['alexpi', 'flex']`**